# python scrapy isn't extracting li text

Tags: python, html, css, xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy and need to extract price(39.500 TL) and li data as text using xpath, css selectors but I've got empty list. This is the one of the requested url: "https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-2004-polo-konfor-rahatlik-guven-812893957/detay" Here's the html snippet:

```html
    <div class="classifiedInfo ">

                        <h3>
                     39.500 TL<input id="priceHistoryFlag" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id="priceHistoryClassifiedId" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id="priceHistoryFavorite" type="hidden" value="">
    <div id="price-history-wrapper" class="price-history-wrapper hidden">

        <div id="price-icon-wrapper" class="price-history-wrapper tipitip-trigger price-history-icon" data-class="price-history"
             data-position="south" data-content="İlan Fiyat Tarihçesi">
        </div>

        <span id="splash-price-history-icon"></span>

        <div id="price-history-dropdown" class="price-history-wrapper price-history-info">

            <div class="section-top">
                <div class="section-title">
                        <span class="for-classified-owner">
                               İlan Fiyat Tarihçesi</span>
                    <span class="for-classified-favourite">
                               Favoriye Eklendikten Sonraki Fiyat Tarihçesi</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="section-main">

                <ul class="price-history-summary">
                    <li class="price-history-summary-item first-price">
                        <p class="history-header for-classified-owner">
                            İlanın Yayınlandığı
    Fiyat</p>
                        <p class="history-header for-classified-favourite">
                            Favoriye Eklendiğindeki Fiyat</p>
                        <p id="initialPriceTemplate" class="history-body">

                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="price-history-summary-item price-holder">
                        <div class="price-change-icon"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="price-history-summary-item second-price">
                        <p class="history-header ">
                            İlanın Şu Anki
    Fiyatı</p>
                        <p class="history-body" id="realPriceTemplate">
                        </p>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <div id="table-wrapper" class="table-wrapper">
                    <table class="price-history-table">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr id="history-row">
                            <td class="for-classified-owner">
                                İlanın Yayınlandığı
    Fiyat<p class="inner-date">Yayınlanma Tarihi:</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="for-classified-favourite">
                                Favoriye Eklendiğindeki Fiyat<p class="inner-date">Favoriye Ekleme Tarihi:</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="history-price"></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <h3 class="no-price-history">
                    <span class="for-classified-owner">
                        İlan yayınlandıktan sonra fiyat değişikliği olmamıştır.</span>
                    <span class="for-classified-favourite">
                            Favoriye eklendikten sonra fiyat değişikliği olmamıştır.</span>

                </h3>


                <h3 class="price-all">
                    <a>
                        Tüm Fiyat Değişimlerini Gör</a>
                </h3>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </h3>
     <h2>
                <a href="/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline/tekirdag"
                           data-click-category="İlan Detay Events"
                           data-click-event="Click - Detay Alanı"
                           data-click-label="Adres Breadcrumb | Tekirdağ"
                        >
                            Tekirdağ</a>
                    <span>/</span>
                                <a href="/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline/tekirdag-suleymanpasa"
                                   data-click-category="İlan Detay Events"
                                   data-click-event="Click - Detay Alanı"
                                   data-click-label="Adres Breadcrumb | Süleymanpaşa"
                                >
                                    Süleymanpaşa</a>
                            <span>/</span>
                                <a href="/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline/tekirdag-suleymanpasa-merkez?address_quarter=41016"
                                   data-click-category="İlan Detay Events"
                                   data-click-event="Click - Detay Alanı"
                                   data-click-label="Adres Breadcrumb | Yavuz Mah."
                                >
                                    Yavuz Mah.</a>
                            </h2><ul class="classifiedInfoList">

        <li>
            <strong>İlan No</strong>&nbsp;
            <span class="classifiedId" id="classifiedId">812893957</span>
            </li>
        <li>
                <strong>
                    İlan Tarihi</strong>&nbsp;
                <span>
                    16 Mayıs 2020</span>
            </li>
        <li>
                    <strong>Marka</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span>Volkswagen&nbsp;</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <strong>Seri</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span>Polo&nbsp;</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <strong>Model</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span>1.4 Basicline&nbsp;</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <strong>Yıl</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span class="">
                     2004</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <strong>Yakıt</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span class="">
                     Benzin &amp; LPG</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <strong>Vites</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span class="">
                     Manuel</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <strong>KM</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span class="">
                     330.000</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <strong>Kasa Tipi</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span class="">
                     Hatchback 5 kapı</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <strong>Motor Gücü</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span class="">
                     75 hp</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <strong>Motor Hacmi</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span class="">
                     1390 cc</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <strong>Çekiş</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span class="">
                     Önden Çekiş</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <strong>Renk</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span class="">
                     Gümüş Gri</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <strong>Garanti</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span class="">
                     Evet</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <strong>Plaka / Uyruk</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span class="">
                     Türkiye (TR) Plakalı</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <strong>Kimden</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span class="">
                     Galeriden</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <strong>Görüntülü Arama İle Görülebilir</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span class="">
                     Evet</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                <strong>Takas</strong>&nbsp;
                    <span>
                        Evet&nbsp;
                    </span>
            </li>
        <li>
            <strong>Durumu</strong>&nbsp;
            <span>
                İkinci El&nbsp;
                </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p class="classifiedIdBox  ">
            <a href="#" rel="nofollow" class="classifiedFeedback">
                    <span>İlan ile İlgili Şikayetim Var</span>
                </a>
            </p>
    </div>
```

> ## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
import scrapy
from ..items import SahibindenItem


class SahibindenSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sahibinden'
    allowed_domains = ['sahibinden.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline']
    main_domain = 'https://www.sahibinden.com'

    def parse(self, response):
        all_product = response.css('.searchResultsLargeThumbnail')
        product_href = all_product.css(' a::attr(href)')

        for urls in product_href:
            product_url = self.main_domain + urls.extract()

            yield scrapy.Request(product_url, callback=self.parse_product)

        next_page_href = response.css('.pageNavTable').css(' a::attr(href)')
        next_page = self.main_domain + next_page_href.extract_first()

        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_product(self, response):
        items = SahibindenItem()

        price = response.xpath("//div[@class='classifiedInfo']/h3/text()").extract()
        print(price)

        all_li = response.css('.classifiedInfo classifiedInfoList')

        for li in all_li:
            list = response.xpath("ul[@class='classifiedInfoList']/li/strong/text()").extract()

            print(list)
```

and the response is :

```
2020-05-17 23:13:39 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.1.0 started (bot: sahibinden)
2020-05-17 23:13:39 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) - [GCC 8.4.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.9.2, Platform Linux-5.3.0-51-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
2020-05-17 23:13:39 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2020-05-17 23:13:39 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'sahibinden',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'sahibinden.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['sahibinden.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
               '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'}
2020-05-17 23:13:40 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 58242402ce332541
2020-05-17 23:13:40 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-05-17 23:13:40 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-05-17 23:13:40 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-05-17 23:13:40 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:40 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-05-17 23:13:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-05-17 23:13:40 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-05-17 23:13:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-05-17 23:13:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline> (referer: None)
2020-05-17 23:13:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-degisensiz-bakimli-polo-803118235/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
2020-05-17 23:13:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-volskwagen-polo-hasar-kayitsiz-822448384/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
[]
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
2020-05-17 23:13:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-hatasiz-degisensiz-temiz-polo-822253807/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
2020-05-17 23:13:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-ada-auto-2005-vw-polo-tam-otomatik-geri-gorus-c.jant-821797291/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline-2005-822478866/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
2020-05-17 23:13:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-2004-hatasiz-wolkswagen-polo-1.4-otomatik-vites-144.000-km-lpg-813215355/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
[]
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-2004-polo-1.4-812991282/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
2020-05-17 23:13:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-polo-ses-sistemli-ve-dokunmatik-ekranli-821632636/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
2020-05-17 23:13:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-2004-polo-temiz-803421269/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-acil-satilik-ww-orjinal-polo-821908778/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
2020-05-17 23:13:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-80.000-km-otomatik-vites-emsalsizz-813558217/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-sahibinden-degisensiz-polo-822189455/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
2020-05-17 23:13:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-temiz-polo-lpgli-garaj-arabasi-822456667/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-ucn-motors-dan-volkswagen-polo-1.4-benzin-lpg-822233466/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-polo-182-binde-hasar-kayitsiz-822226495/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-sahibinden-vw-polo%2Corijinal-89000-km-822464905/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-2004-polo-konfor-rahatlik-guven-812893957/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-clb-motors-dan-hatasiz-plusboyasiz-plustramersiz-plus2004-plus1.4-basicline-820974275/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-2004-model-volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline-68.000-km-1-parca-boya-821592226/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
[]
[]
[]
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-degisensiz-bakimli-polo-803118235/detay> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-bayan-ogretmenden-masrafsiz-yakit-cimrisi-polo-820957643/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-sahibinden-821523592/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-bayan-sahibinden-otomatik-kazasiz-boyasiz-essiz-821068715/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-bayandan-temiz-polo-821199738/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-sahibinden-satilik-temiz-polo-821856019/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
[]
[]
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-boyasiz-2004-model-sikintisiz-araba-821878097/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
[]
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-sahibinde-temiz-2005-polo-682747652/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-yusuf-siner-den-2004-polo-1.4-basicline-133.000-km-de-emsalsizz-822097462/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-klimali-bej-doseme-dusuk-km-815863726/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-alicisini-uzmez-masrafsizdir-821575509/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-sahibinden-2004-lpgli-temiz-polo-821966323/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-askeri-personel-den-2004-temiz-polo-810641293/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-sahibinden-cok-duzgun-arac-822159073/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
2020-05-17 23:13:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-2004-model-ww-polo-1.4-16v-klimali-137bin-km-de-benzin-lpg-822173219/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
2020-05-17 23:13:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-dusuk-km-masrafsiz-polo-821322269/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
2020-05-17 23:13:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-dogan-otomotivden-hatasiz-boyasiz-polo-lpgli-822188799/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
2020-05-17 23:13:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-volkswagen-polo-2005-orjinal-140.000-km-45.000-tl-821912561/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
[]
[]
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-136-binde-bayandan-temiz-polo-822197188/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
2020-05-17 23:13:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-bakmadan-gecme-uygun-arac-822476317/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
[]
[]
[]
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-sahibinden-polo-lpg-li-175-binde-degisen-ve-hasar-kaydi-yok-821620290/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline?pagingOffset=20)
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-2004-model-ww-polo-1.4-basicline-hatasiz-115-binde-821659634/detay> (referer: https://www.sahibinden.com/volkswagen-polo-1.4-basicline)
[]
2020-05-17 23:13:43 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-05-17 23:13:43 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 27352,
 'downloader/request_count': 44,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 44,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 4262800,
 'downloader/response_count': 44,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 44,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 21,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 3.676599,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 20, 13, 43, 835411),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 45,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 54013952,
 'memusage/startup': 54013952,
 'request_depth_max': 3,
 'response_received_count': 44,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 43,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 43,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 43,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 43,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 20, 13, 40, 158812)}
2020-05-17 23:13:43 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: that is  -------  all_li = response.css('.classifiedInfo')  but I've got still empty list

Answer (score 2):

if you print:

```
response.text
```

you will see that the content of the webpage is being encrypted by a javascript script. Not sure if there is a solution for that.

Comment: I've uploaded. If there is a chance to scrape, I will be appreciated.

Comment: @FaikYucesoy uploaded what?

Comment: Ohh sorry dude, I am really tired. I thought you mean upload the output when you said print response.text:)) Thanks for helping.

Comment: hhh np, I was just trying to tell you that you cant extract a single string since the content of the page is encrypted. @FaikYucesoy

Comment: actually, if I extract all the data, I will reorganize the data. That won't be problem. Is there a way to extract all data?

Comment: not really, unfortunately, you can't get a single HTML element